How to make equal width for two columns from different GridPane in JavaFX?
I want to do something like this:

using TitledPane with GridPane inside. In every GridPane I have two columns - label column and control column. And I want the label column in the top TitlePane to have the same width as the bottom one. Because otherwise it looks terrible. And of course, I can't use fixed width in pixels because label texts depend on user language.
This is my code:
public class MyGridPanes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane gridPane1 = new GridPane();
        gridPane1.add(new Label("One two three"), 0, 0);
        gridPane1.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        gridPane1.setHgap(20);
        var titledPane1 = new TitledPane("Top", gridPane1);
        titledPane1.setCollapsible(false);

        GridPane gridPane2 = new GridPane();
        gridPane2.setHgap(20);
        gridPane2.add(new Label("Four five six seven"), 0, 0);
        gridPane2.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        var titledPane2 = new TitledPane("Bottom", gridPane2);
        titledPane2.setCollapsible(false);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(titledPane1, titledPane2), 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

And this is my result:

Could anyone say how to do it?

Find the length of the longest Label width. Set all Label minWidth to that length.

If your titled panes are not collapsible (so you don't need any of the actual title pane functionality) another solution may be to use a single grid pane and just style the "Top" and "Bottom" labels (which would have colspan=2) to look like titles. That might be easier than other solutions, though it wouldn't generalize well if you did want collapsible panes.

+1 for @SedJ601 & @jewelsea suggestions.
But if you have many labels/gridPanes to handle or if it is hard to maintain all labels in one list or if you don't want any custom control, you can try the below approach.
The general idea is: we go through all the nodes of first column in all gridPanes and keep track of the their widths to determine the max width. And this maxWidth is set as the ColumnConstraint minWidth to all gridPanes.
You can have a static utility method as below, where you just pass the gridPanes:
/**
 * Builds a common first column constraints for the provided gridPanes.
 * @param gridPanes
 */
private static void buildFirstColumnConstraint(GridPane... gridPanes) {
    /* Column constraint key. */
    final String COLUMN_INDEX_CONSTRAINT = "gridpane-column";

    /* Checks if the node is a first column node or not. */
    Predicate<Node> isFirstColumn = node ->{
        Integer constraint = (Integer) node.getProperties().get(COLUMN_INDEX_CONSTRAINT);
        return constraint != null && constraint == 0;
    };

    /* Keep track of the max width. */
    DoubleProperty maxWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    ChangeListener<Number> widthListener = (obs, old, val) -> {
        if (val.doubleValue() > maxWidth.get()) {
            maxWidth.set(val.doubleValue());
        }
    };

    // Bind the minWidth to the calculated width
    final ColumnConstraints constraint = new ColumnConstraints();
    constraint.minWidthProperty().bind(maxWidth);

    // Go through each gridPane and set the first constraint
    Stream.of(gridPanes).forEach(gridPane -> {
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(0,constraint);

        // Filter for all first column children and add the widthListener to them
        gridPane.getChildren().stream().filter(isFirstColumn)
                .map(node -> (Region) node)
                .forEach(region -> region.widthProperty().addListener(widthListener));
    });
}

Below is the full demo code:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GridPane_Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {


        GridPane gridPane1 = buildGrid("One", "One Two");
        var titledPane1 = new TitledPane("Top", gridPane1);
        titledPane1.setCollapsible(false);

        GridPane gridPane2 = buildGrid("One Two Three", "One Two Three Four");
        var titledPane2 = new TitledPane("Bottom", gridPane2);
        titledPane2.setCollapsible(false);

        buildFirstColumnConstraint(gridPane1, gridPane2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(titledPane1, titledPane2), 400, 220);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private GridPane buildGrid(String label1, String label2) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(20);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.addRow(0, new Label(label1), new TextField());
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Label(label2), new TextField());
        return gridPane;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a common first column constraints for the provided gridPanes.
     *
     * @param gridPanes
     */
    private static void buildFirstColumnConstraint(GridPane... gridPanes) {
        /* Column constraint key. */
        final String COLUMN_INDEX_CONSTRAINT = "gridpane-column";

        /* Checks if the node is a first column node or not. */
        Predicate<Node> isFirstColumn = node -> {
            Integer constraint = (Integer) node.getProperties().get(COLUMN_INDEX_CONSTRAINT);
            return constraint != null && constraint == 0;
        };

        /* Keep track of the max width. */
        DoubleProperty maxWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        ChangeListener<Number> widthListener = (obs, old, val) -> {
            if (val.doubleValue() > maxWidth.get()) {
                maxWidth.set(val.doubleValue());
            }
        };

        // Bind the minWidth to the calculated width
        final ColumnConstraints constraint = new ColumnConstraints();
        constraint.minWidthProperty().bind(maxWidth);

        // Go through each gridPane and set the first constraint
        Stream.of(gridPanes).forEach(gridPane -> {
            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(0, constraint);

            // Filter for all first column children and add the widthListener to them
            gridPane.getChildren().stream().filter(isFirstColumn)
                    .map(node -> (Region) node)
                    .forEach(region -> region.widthProperty().addListener(widthListener));
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Perhaps the best solution would be to use a custom layout pane and perform the label layout within a layout pass when layoutChildren is called.  But that is complicated to do well, so I won't try it here.
I have created the solution below, which you could consider.  It is a bit brittle and complicated, so you may prefer the simpler answers provided by SedJ601 or Sai.
The approach is to calculate the width of the longest label after all the grids are added to a scene in a window and CSS and layout have been applied.
Then the example offers two solutions:

Set the min width of all labels to the width of the longest label (as originally suggested by SedJ in comments). TitledGridContainer::sizeLabels method.

OR

Set a column constraint for the first column in each grid to the width of the longest label (as originally suggested by Sai's answer). TitledGridContainer::sizeLabelColumn method.


MyGridPanes.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyGridPanes extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TitledGridContainer layout = new TitledGridContainer(
                10,
                new TitledGrid("Top", "One two three"),
                new TitledGrid("Bottom", "Four five six seven", "")
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // an example of sizing all labels in all grids.
        //layout.sizeLabels();
        
        // alternate example of sizing columns of labels.
        layout.sizeLabelColumn();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

TitledGridContainer.java
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TitledGridContainer extends VBox {
    private final List<TitledGrid> managedGrids;

    public TitledGridContainer(double spacing, TitledGrid... titledGrid) {
        super(spacing, titledGrid);

        managedGrids = Arrays.asList(titledGrid);
    }

    public void sizeLabels() {
        double longestLabelWidth = calcRequiredLabelSize();

        getAllLabels().forEach(label ->
                label.setMinWidth(longestLabelWidth)
        );
    }

    public void sizeLabelColumn() {
        double longestLabelWidth = calcRequiredLabelSize();

        managedGrids.forEach(titledGrid ->
                titledGrid
                        .getLabelColumnConstraints()
                        .setMinWidth(longestLabelWidth)
        );
    }

    private double calcRequiredLabelSize() {
        if (getScene() == null || getScene().getWindow() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Titled grid label sizing can only be performed when the grid is in a scene displayed in a window, scene=%s, window=%s"
                            .formatted(
                                    getScene(),
                                    getScene() == null
                                            ? null
                                            : getScene().getWindow()
                            )
            );
        }

        applyCss();
        layout();

        return getAllLabels()
                .map(Region::getWidth)
                .reduce(Double::max)
                .orElse(0d);
    }

    private Stream<Label> getAllLabels() {
        return managedGrids.stream()
                .flatMap(grid ->
                        grid.getLabels().stream()
                );
    }
}

TitledGrid.java
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TitledGrid extends TitledPane {
    private final List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ColumnConstraints labelColumnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();

    public TitledGrid(String title, String... labelText) {
        super();
        setText(title);
        setCollapsible(false);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        setContent(gridPane);
        gridPane.setHgap(20);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(labelColumnConstraints);

        int row = 0;
        for (String text: labelText) {
            Label label = new Label(text);
            labels.add(label);

            gridPane.addRow(row++, label, new TextField());
        }
    }

    public List<Label> getLabels() {
        return labels;
    }

    public ColumnConstraints getLabelColumnConstraints() {
        return labelColumnConstraints;
    }
}


One way you can do this is to find the Label with the longest width and set the min width of all labels to that width.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        List<Label> labelList = new ArrayList();
        
        GridPane gridPane1 = new GridPane();
        Label label1 = new Label("One two three");
        labelList.add(label1);
        gridPane1.add(label1, 0, 0);
        gridPane1.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        gridPane1.setHgap(20);
        var titledPane1 = new TitledPane("Top", gridPane1);
        titledPane1.setCollapsible(false);

        GridPane gridPane2 = new GridPane();
        Label label2 = new Label("One two three");
        labelList.add(label2);
        gridPane2.setHgap(20);
        gridPane2.add(label2, 0, 0);
        gridPane2.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        var titledPane2 = new TitledPane("Bottom", gridPane2);
        titledPane2.setCollapsible(false);

        findLongestLabelWidthAndSetLabelMinWidth(labelList);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(titledPane1, titledPane2), 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    void findLongestLabelWidthAndSetLabelMinWidth(List<Label> labelList)
    {
        double maxWidth = 0;
        for (Label label : labelList) 
        {
            Text text = new Text(label.getText());
            double textWidth = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
            if (textWidth > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = textWidth;
            }
        }
        
        for (Label label : labelList) 
        {
            label.setMinWidth(maxWidth);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



Consider just… not drawing lines around everything.  Doing so is a UI design mistake that programmers make quite often, because their conceptual image of the UI is groupings.  That concept is fine, but it is not necessary to draw actual lines around groups of UI controls.  In fact, it often reduces readability of the overall UI.  As you are discovering, lines break up alignment, both visually and programmatically.
Instead, just make your headings as text objects, without TitledPanes or lines of any sort.  The visual organization itself is enough to make your groupings clear.
And, of course, this makes it easy to align all your labels;  you can simply use a single GridPane:
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class ScoringDialog
extends Application {
    private ComboBox<String> matchField;
    private ComboBox<Integer> stageField;
    private ComboBox<String> competitorField;

    private Spinner<Integer> missesField;
    private Spinner<Integer> proceduralsField;

    private Spinner<Integer> aHitsField;
    private Spinner<Integer> cHitsField;
    private Spinner<Integer> dHitsField;

    private TextField timeField;
    private TextFormatter<Number> timeFormatter;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        matchField = new ComboBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("m1", "m2", "m3"));

        stageField = new ComboBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10));

        competitorField = new ComboBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "l1, m1", "l1, m2", "l1, m3",
                "l2, m1", "l2, m2", "l2, m3",
                "l3, m1", "l3, m2", "l3, m3"));

        matchField.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        stageField.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        competitorField.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        missesField = new Spinner<>(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);
        proceduralsField = new Spinner<>(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);

        aHitsField = new Spinner<>(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);
        cHitsField = new Spinner<>(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);
        dHitsField = new Spinner<>(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);

        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
        timeFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new NumberStringConverter(format));
        timeFormatter.setValue(111.0);

        timeField = new TextField();
        timeField.setTextFormatter(timeFormatter);
        timeField.setEditable(false);


        Spinner<?>[] spinners = {
            missesField,
            proceduralsField,
            aHitsField,
            cHitsField,
            dHitsField,
        };
        for (Spinner<?> spinner : spinners) {
            spinner.getStyleClass().add(
                Spinner.STYLE_CLASS_ARROWS_ON_RIGHT_HORIZONTAL);
        }

        Label matchLabel = new Label("Match: ");
        matchLabel.setLabelFor(matchField);

        Label stageLabel = new Label("Stage: ");
        stageLabel.setLabelFor(stageField);

        Label competitorLabel = new Label("Competitor: ");
        competitorLabel.setLabelFor(competitorField);

        Label missesLabel = new Label("Misses: ");
        missesLabel.setLabelFor(missesField);

        Label proceduralsLabel = new Label("Procedurals: ");
        proceduralsLabel.setLabelFor(proceduralsField);

        Label aHitsLabel = new Label("A Hits: ");
        aHitsLabel.setLabelFor(aHitsField);

        Label cHitsLabel = new Label("C Hits: ");
        cHitsLabel.setLabelFor(cHitsField);

        Label dHitsLabel = new Label("D Hits: ");
        dHitsLabel.setLabelFor(dHitsField);

        Label timeLabel = new Label("Total time: ");
        timeLabel.setLabelFor(timeField);

        Node coordinatesHeading = createHeading("Coordinates");
        Node penaltiesHeading = createHeading("Penalties");
        Node scoringHeading = createHeading("Scoring");
        Node timeHeading = createHeading("Time");

        Label horizontalSpacer = new Label();
        Label verticalSpacer = new Label();

        Button confirmButton = new Button("Confirm");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane(0, 3);

        grid.add(coordinatesHeading, 0, 0, 3, 1);
        grid.add(matchLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(matchField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(stageLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(stageField, 2, 2);
        grid.add(competitorLabel, 1, 3);
        grid.add(competitorField, 2, 3);

        grid.add(penaltiesHeading, 0, 5, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("  "), 0, 6);
        grid.add(missesLabel, 1, 6);
        grid.add(missesField, 2, 6);
        grid.add(proceduralsLabel, 1, 7);
        grid.add(proceduralsField, 2, 7);

        grid.add(scoringHeading, 4, 0, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("  "), 4, 1);
        grid.add(aHitsLabel, 5, 1);
        grid.add(aHitsField, 6, 1);
        grid.add(cHitsLabel, 5, 2);
        grid.add(cHitsField, 6, 2);
        grid.add(dHitsLabel, 5, 3);
        grid.add(dHitsField, 6, 3);

        grid.add(timeHeading, 4, 5, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("  "), 4, 6);
        grid.add(timeLabel, 5, 6);
        grid.add(timeField, 6, 6);

        grid.add(horizontalSpacer, 3, 0, 1, GridPane.REMAINING);
        grid.add(verticalSpacer, 0, 4, GridPane.REMAINING, 1);
        GridPane.setMargin(horizontalSpacer, new Insets(0, 12, 0, 0));
        GridPane.setMargin(verticalSpacer, new Insets(12, 0, 0, 0));

        grid.add(confirmButton, 0, 8, GridPane.REMAINING, 1);

        GridPane.setHalignment(confirmButton, HPos.RIGHT);
        GridPane.setMargin(confirmButton, new Insets(6, 0, 0, 0));

        grid.setPadding(new Insets(6));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
        stage.setTitle("Rapid Scoring");
        stage.show();
    }

    private Node createHeading(String text) {
        Text heading = new Text(text);
        heading.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 120%;");
        return heading;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Doing so is a UI design mistake that programmers make quite often... I absolutely agree with you.
